# How to implement last visited functionality for articles in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I have this model of `Article` where users can post articles, add comments, etc. I want to add a filter where it can filter `Articles` according to user **which has visited the last `Article`** or **commented on the last `Article`.**

Please guide me on how can I achieve this functionality in *Django/DRF*.

This is my models:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="ARTICLE_ID")
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abstract=models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    files=models.ManyToManyField('DocumentModel', related_name='file_documents',related_query_name='select_files', blank=True)
    published=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='tags', blank=True)
    isDraft=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    isFavourite=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="articles")
    
   
    def get_id(self):
        return self.headline + ' belongs to ' + 'id ' + str(self.id)

    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "Articles"
        ordering=("id", "headline", "abstract", "content",  "published", "isDraft", "created_by")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.headline}'
```

**EDITED**

This is the following I have implemented

**Articles.py**

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="ARTICLE_ID")
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abstract=models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    files=models.ManyToManyField('DocumentModel', related_name='file_documents',related_query_name='select_files', blank=True)
    published=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='tags', blank=True)
    isDraft=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    isFavourite=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="articles")
    
    
   
    def get_id(self):
        return self.headline + ' belongs to ' + 'id ' + str(self.id)

    def seen_by_user(self, user):
        return self.articleseenrecord_set.objects.filter(user=user).exists()

    @register.simple_tag
    def article_seen_by_user(article, user):
        return article.seen_by_user(user)
    

    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural= "Articles"
        ordering=("id", "headline", "abstract", "content",  "published", "isDraft", "created_by")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.headline}'
```

This is I created my `ArticleSeenRecord`:

```py
class ArticleSeenRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is how I tried to serialize:

**serializers.py**

```py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

   #serializer for getting username of User
    created_by=serializers.CharField(source='created_by.username', read_only=True)
    files=DocumentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    isFavourite=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    tags=serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tags.objects.all(), slug_field="tag")
    seen_by_user=serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model= Article
        fields = ["id", "headline", "abstract", "seen_by_user", "content",   "published",  "isDraft", "isFavourite", "tags", 'files', 'created_by' ]
```

After checking I get the following error in response:

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "headline": "Article 1",
            "abstract": "Abstract 1",
            "seen_by_user": "<bound method Article.seen_by_user of <Article: Article 1>>",
            "content": "content 1",
            "published": "2022-10-20",
            "isDraft": true,
            "isFavourite": [
                1
            ],
            "tags": [
                "Python",
                "C++"
            ],
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "document": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploaded_files/6Dp4gG4pi8Wm4ficssTD6o.pdf",
                    "filesize": "122 KB",
                    "filename": "resume.pdf",
                    "mimetype": "application/pdf",
                    "created_at": "2022-10-20"
                }
            ],
            "created_by": "abdullahroshan"
        },
```

I get `"seen_by_user": "<bound method Article.seen_by_user of <Article: Article 1>>"` error in response.

Also, I don't know how to use this template tag and check that the user has viewed an article.

This is `Articles` viewset:

```py
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):



    serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]

    pagination_class=StandardResultSetPagination
    filter_backends= (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields= ['headline', 'isDraft']
    search_fields=['headline']
    ordering_fields = ['id']

 def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj=super().get_object(queryset)
        record, created = ArticleSeenRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, article=obj)
        return obj
```

***UPDATED***

Hi, thanks for the update, I have implemented every step, and there is currently an error that is popping

After implementing a serializer like this

**`ArticleSerializer`**

```py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


   #serializer for getting username of User
    created_by=serializers.CharField(source='created_by.username', read_only=True)
    files=DocumentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    isFavourite=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    tags=serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tags.objects.all(), slug_field="tag")
    seen_by_user=serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model= Article
        fields = ["id", "headline", "seen_by_user", "abstract", "content",  "published",  "isDraft", "isFavourite", "tags", 'files',  'created_by'  ]  
        
       
    def get_seen_by_user(self, instance):
        return instance.seen_by_user(article, self.context['request'].user)
```

And in Views addling like this:

```py
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class=ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]

    pagination_class=StandardResultSetPagination
    filter_backends= (DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter, filters.SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields= ['headline', 'isDraft']
    search_fields=['headline']
    ordering_fields = ['id']

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super().get_object(queryset)
        record, created=ArticleSeenRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, article=obj)
        return obj    
   
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

I get the below error:

```
return instance.seen_by_user(article, self.context['request'].user)
NameError: name 'article' is not defined
```

Here the article is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer here from a previous question, which is almost identical.

You could create an extra table.

```
class ArticleSeenRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("django.contrib.auth.models.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then in your article view, create a new record when one doesn't exist, for that article combined with the authenticated user.

```
class ArticleDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'home/article_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj =  super().get_object(queryset)
        record, created =  ArticleSeenRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, article=obj)
        return obj
   

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def seen_by_user(self, user):
         return self.atricleseenrecord_set.objects.filter(user=user).exists()
```

I added the extra function here. You will also need to add a template tag which you can ideally copy from this example

```
@register.simple_tag
def article_seen_by_user(article, user):
    return article.seen_by_user(user)
```

For further guidance on how to use and register custom template tags, please refer to this page of the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Specifically this section:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag

**EDIT**
Thanks for your responses and for updating your answer, I understand your point and will respond based on the expanded question.

You have pretty much implemented perfectly, the only difference would be on your serialiser - you should change the `seen_by_user` field from a `CharField` to:

```
seen_by_user = serialisers.SerializerMethodField()
```

And this will solve your problem of not getting the `seen_by_user` field properly serialised. Then you can define a function  on the serialiser, for example:

```
def get_seen_by_user(self, instance):
    return instance.seen_by_user(article, self.context['request'].user)
```

and finally, you can add the request into the serialiser context like so:

```
class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

Comment: i am still not able to find the solution .... i dont know how to start ..

Comment: I think that it would be better that you read my answer and try to implement this, if you run have trouble implementing this then we can discuss the specific problems you encounter

Comment: I have implemented the following, now how can i know that its working? use queryset?

Comment: its also giving this after serializing "<bound method Article.seen_by_user of <Article: Article 1>>"

Comment: Please update your answer with the new code for me to see, along with any errors and traceback associated. Thanks

Comment: i have edited the code, please check where i am wrong ..

Comment: question updated, as per import random's review comment, and also as per the update and edited question. This should solve your problem now, sorry about the confusion :) let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: error again xD,
i have tried implementing and its saying that article is not defined @Swift

Comment: in get_seen_by_user function

Comment: I'm ever so sorry, please replace "article" with "instance"